# How to sort menu items in the top menu in alphabetical order in magento2 frontend

Tags: magento2, sorting, topmenu

Is there any way to sort menu items(Categories) showing in Magento in alphabetical order?

Comment: Please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/357919/82670

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution as of now for your query sorting the menu.

1. Moving the menu items manualyy by dragging them and placing them in the
   admin panel itself.

For this log into the admin panel -> Catalog -> Categories and select and drag a menu item you wish to place it before or after a menu item and click ok.

please see the attached video for more ref.

[image]

Another solution is in code level , please let me know if it is needed.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: yes, I am looking for a code-level solution. I tried a lot but not succeded

Comment: @midhun Please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/357919/82670

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Html**

**Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Html;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Menu;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Cache identities
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $identities = [];

    /**
     * Top menu data tree
     *
     * @var Node
     */
    protected $_menu;

    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    private $nodeFactory;

    /**
     * @var TreeFactory
     */
    private $treeFactory;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
     * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->treeFactory = $treeFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $nodeFactory,
            $treeFactory,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get block cache life time
     *
     * @return int
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        return parent::getCacheLifetime() ?: 3600;
    }

    /**
     * Get top menu html
     *
     * @param string $outermostClass
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
    {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before',
            ['menu' => $this->getMenu(), 'block' => $this, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
        );

        $this->getMenu()->setOutermostClass($outermostClass);
        $this->getMenu()->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);

        $transportObject = new DataObject(
            [
                'html' => $this->_getHtml(
                    $this->getMenu(),
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ),
            ]
        );

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after',
            ['menu' => $this->getMenu(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
        );

        return $transportObject->getHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Count All Subnavigation Items
     *
     * @param Menu $items
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _countItems($items)
    {
        $total = $items->count();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            /** @var $item Menu\Item */
            if ($item->hasChildren()) {
                $total += $this->_countItems($item->getChildren());
            }
        }
        return $total;
    }

    /**
     * Building Array with Column Brake Stops
     *
     * @param Menu $items
     * @param int $limit
     * @return array|void
     *
     * @todo: Add Depth Level limit, and better logic for columns
     */
    protected function _columnBrake($items, $limit)
    {
        $total = $this->_countItems($items);
        if ($total <= $limit) {
            return;
        }

        $result[] = ['total' => $total, 'max' => (int) ceil($total / ceil($total / $limit))];

        $count = 0;
        $firstCol = true;

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $place = $this->_countItems($item->getChildren()) + 1;
            $count += $place;

            if ($place >= $limit) {
                $colbrake = !$firstCol;
                $count = 0;
            } elseif ($count >= $limit) {
                $colbrake = !$firstCol;
                $count = $place;
            } else {
                $colbrake = false;
            }

            $result[] = ['place' => $place, 'colbrake' => $colbrake];

            $firstCol = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Add sub menu HTML code for current menu item
     *
     * @param Node $child
     * @param string $childLevel
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @return string HTML code
     */
    protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {
        $html = '';
        if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $colStops = [];
        if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
            $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
        }

        $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
     *
     * @param Node $menuTree
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @param array $colBrakes
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getHtml(
        Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        array $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $childLevel = $this->getChildLevel($menuTree->getLevel());
        $this->removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent($children, $childLevel);

        $counter = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        /* Reorder category */
        $children = $this->getRerderCateogry($children);

        /** @var Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter === 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter === $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel === 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $this->setCurrentClass($child, $outermostClass);
            }

            if ($this->shouldAddNewColumn($colBrakes, $counter)) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $child->getName()
            ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                $child,
                $childLevel,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $limit
            ) . '</li>';
            $counter++;
        }

        if (is_array($colBrakes) && !empty($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Reorder category
     *
     * @param Node $children
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRerderCateogry($children)
    {
        $newOrderCat = $newOrderCatObj = [];
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $alphaChar = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $child->getName());
            $newOrderCat[$alphaChar] = $child;
        }
        ksort($newOrderCat);
        foreach ($newOrderCat as $newOrderCatKey => $newOrderCatVal) {
            $newOrderCatObj[] = $newOrderCatVal;
        }
        return $newOrderCatObj;
    }

    /**
     * Generates string with all attributes that should be present in menu item element
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getRenderedMenuItemAttributes(Node $item)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach ($this->_getMenuItemAttributes($item) as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $html .= ' ' . $attributeName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attributeValue) . '"';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's attributes
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemAttributes(Node $item)
    {
        return ['class' => implode(' ', $this->_getMenuItemClasses($item))];
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's classes
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemClasses(Node $item)
    {
        $classes = [
            'level' . $item->getLevel(),
            $item->getPositionClass(),
        ];

        if ($item->getIsCategory()) {
            $classes[] = 'category-item';
        }

        if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }

        if ($item->getIsActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        } elseif ($item->getHasActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'has-active';
        }

        if ($item->getIsLast()) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }

        if ($item->getClass()) {
            $classes[] = $item->getClass();
        }

        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        return $classes;
    }

    /**
     * Add identity
     *
     * @param string|array $identity
     * @return void
     */
    public function addIdentity($identity)
    {
        if (!in_array($identity, $this->identities)) {
            $this->identities[] = $identity;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get identities
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return $this->identities;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags array for saving cache
     *
     * @return array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected function getCacheTags()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getCacheTags(), $this->getIdentities());
    }

    /**
     * Get menu object.
     *
     * Creates Tree root node object.
     * The creation logic was moved from class constructor into separate method.
     *
     * @return Node
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        if (!$this->_menu) {
            $this->_menu = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [],
                    'idField' => 'root',
                    'tree' => $this->treeFactory->create(),
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this->_menu;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children from collection when the parent is not active
     *
     * @param Collection $children
     * @param int $childLevel
     * @return void
     */
    private function removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent(Collection $children, int $childLevel): void
    {
        /** @var Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
                $children->delete($child);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child level based on parent level
     *
     * @param int $parentLevel
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function getChildLevel($parentLevel): int
    {
        return $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Check if new column should be added.
     *
     * @param array $colBrakes
     * @param int $counter
     * @return bool
     */
    private function shouldAddNewColumn(array $colBrakes, int $counter): bool
    {
        return count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake'];
    }

    /**
     * Set current class.
     *
     * @param Node $child
     * @param string $outermostClass
     */
    private function setCurrentClass(Node $child, string $outermostClass): void
    {
        $currentClass = $child->getClass();
        if (empty($currentClass)) {
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        } else {
            $child->setClass($currentClass . ' ' . $outermostClass);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]